Twilio Voice SDK Client Hanging Up Instantly
I am using Vue as my frontend. I am looking to integrate with Twilio's Voice SDK to place outgoing calls and receiving incoming calls. I have setup my TwilML app, etc. and the plumbing of my token from my backend to the frontend. I am able to place a call to a hardcoded number, I hear a ringtone, browser asks for microphone permissions, but afterwards it instantaneously hangs up. I noticed the thread here:Twilio JS client hanging up immediately
I followed several of the answers, but to no avail.
Here is my current code:
Twilio Component (.vue):
<template>
  <div class="twilio-call">
    <button @click="makeCall" :disabled="isCalling">
      {{ isCalling ? "Calling..." : "Call" }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as messagingApi from "../../../api/messaging.js";
import * as twilioVoiceSDK from "../../../utils/twilio.js"

export default {
  name: "TwilioCall",
  data() {
    return {
      twilioToken:
        "", 
      toNumber: "+1HardcodedNumber", 
      isCalling: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async makeCall() {
      this.twilioToken = await messagingApi.getTwilioToken();

      if (this.isCalling) return;

      try {
        this.isCalling = true;

        // Initialize Twilio Device
        if (!twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice()) {
          twilioVoiceSDK.createDevice(this.twilioToken);

          // Handle error events
          twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("error", (error) => {
            console.error("Twilio Error:", error);
            this.isCalling = false;
          });
        }

        // Register the Twilio device
        await twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().register();

        // Make a call to the hardcoded number
        const callParams = { To: this.toNumber };
        const call = await twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().connect(callParams);

        // Handle disconnect event
        call.on("disconnect", () => {
          this.isCalling = false;
          console.log("Call disconnected");
        });

        // Add event listeners to capture detailed logs
        twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("ready", () =>
          console.log("Twilio Device is ready.")
        );
        twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("error", (error) =>
          console.error("Twilio Device Error:", error)
        );
        twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("connect", (conn) =>
          console.log("Twilio Connection established:", conn)
        );
        twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("disconnect", (conn) =>
          console.log("Twilio Connection disconnected:", conn)
        );
        twilioVoiceSDK.getDevice().on("incoming", (conn) =>
          console.log("Incoming call:", conn)
        );

        console.log("Calling:", this.toNumber);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error making call:", error);
        this.isCalling = false;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.twilio-call {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>


Twilio.js in utils
import { Device } from '@twilio/voice-sdk';

/**
 * Do NOT bind this object in Vue. Vue wraps proxies around it and that causes issues.
 *
 * @type { import('@twilio/voice-sdk').Device }
 */
let device = null;

/**
 * @param {String} token
 * @returns {Device}
 */
export function createDevice(token) {
    return device = new Device(token, {
        // See https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptions
        logLevel: 0,
        // Set Opus as our preferred codec. Opus generally performs better, requiring less bandwidth and
        // providing better audio quality in restrained network conditions.
        codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
    });
}

/**
 * @returns { import('@twilio/voice-sdk').Device }
 */
export function getDevice() {
    return device;
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Vue wrapped the variable in a proxy that made it unable for the TwilioVoiceSDK to properly function. Using markraw by Vue for the variable to not be wrapped as a proxy was the solution.
